# Impose conditions on the solutions of a given set of equations in order to get three distinct solutions for the three variables.

Tags: polynomials

Solve the system of equations 
\begin{align}x + y + z &= a\\
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 &= b^2\\
xy &= z^2,\end{align}
 where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Give the condition on $a$ and $b$ so that $x,y$ and $z$ are distinct. I solved for $x,y,z$. But I couldn't understand how to impose conditions on them to make them unique.

Comment: What is your solution for $x,y,z$ ?

Comment: I solved it and got z = (a^2 - b^2) / 2a and x and y I got really very unusual answer in terms of a and b

Comment: $x,y,z$ distinct means they are different $x\ne y\land x\ne z\land y\ne z$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: plugging $$z=a-x-y$$ in the second and third equation we obtain:
$$a^2-2ax-2ay-b^2+2x^2+2xy+2y^2=0$$ (I)
$$-a^2+2ax+2ay-x^2-xy-y^2=0$$ (II)
multiplying (II) by $2$ and adding to (I) we get
$$-a^2+2ax+2ay-b^2=0$$(III)
this equation is linear in $x,y$ and you can use this to compute the other variables.

Comment: This would help me to get the values of x,y, and z , but how do i prove the second part of the question

Comment: i think the equations for $x,y$ are quadratic

Comment: Yes they are quadratic , but I do get some values(they are very long expressions,though), but how do I impose the condition for a,b to make them unique?

Comment: the discriminante must be zero

Comment: Why should the discriminant be zero?

Comment: that there is a unique solution